# Retrieve a list of CSS classes from multiple css file to be displayed in a drop down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to dig into multiple CSS files to retrieve the CSS classes that are available in each file. I would then like to display those in a drop down menu.

I'm curious if it's possible to retrieve a list of classes directly from a CSS file that way?

Comment: not from the file, not without parsing the css. but you can certainly load that css into the browser, then pull the details the browser's innards via documents.styleSheets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the javascript to retrieve the rules from the stylesheets in use. You may need to further parse the results depending on exactly what you want. I ran this in Chrome version 39. Hope this helps.

```
for(var s=0; s<document.styleSheets.length; s++){
    if(document.styleSheets[s].rules != null){
        for(var r=0; r<document.styleSheets[s].rules.length; r++){
            console.log(document.styleSheets[s].rules[r].cssText);
        }
    }
}
```